# h2 cluster with file based database

Tags: java, database, cluster-computing, h2

I have set up an h2 cluster but cannot connect via the console or using a datasource all I get is this:

```
IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"; "E:/baseDirDefinedInServerConnection/myDB,localhost:1112/myDB" [90031-176] 90031/90031 (Help)
```

I have configured 2 servers  thus:

```
java -cp h2-1.3.167.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 1111 -tcpAllowOthers -baseDir E:\myBaseDir 
at tcp://myIp:1111 (others can connect)

java -cp h2-1.3.167.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 1112 -tcpAllowOthers -baseDir E:\myBaseDir\server
at tcp://myIp:1112 (others can connect)
```

So you see I have one database in a directory (this has been created) and another database in another directory.  Both are up and running.

I have run the cluster tool thus:

```
java -cp h2-1.3.167.jar org.h2.tools.CreateCluster -urlSource jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:1111/myDB -urlTarget jdbc:h2
:tcp://localhost:1112/myDB -user username -password pass -serverList localhost:1111,localhost:1112
```

And it all looks good.  If I try to connect thorugh the console without the cluster list I get this message, which proves we are in clustered mode, which is good:

```
Clustering error - database currently runs in cluster mode, server list: 'localhost:1111,localhost:1112'" [
```

I have checked the permissions on the directories and all has read/write access.
Yes this is a windows machine.
Using H2 version:
Bundle-Vendor: H2 Group
Bundle-Version: 1.3.167

Any ideas what I might have done wrong?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you already found out that one should connect like this
`jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:1111,localhost:1112/myDB`